# Is there a sorted data structure with logarithmic time insertion, deletion and find (with distance)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have a sorted array in which I find number of items less than particular value using binary search (`std::upper_bound`) in `O(logn)` time.
Now I want to insert and delete from this array while keeping it sorted. I want the overall complexity to be `O(logn)`.

I know that using binary search tree or `std::multiset` I can do insertion, deletion and upper_bound in `O(logn)` but I am not able do get the distance/index (`std::distance` is `O(n)` for sets) in logarithmic time.

So is there a way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Please amend your question - an array by itself is a linear data structure so that insertion or deletion wouldn't be cheap as you expected.

Comment: Depending on how big your data is a sorted array benefits from contiguity (being cache friendly) so you may get better performance if you just keep using the array, inserting/ deleting wherever `std::lower_bound`/`std::upper_bound` tells you.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the suggested question, this is looking for better than `O(n)`  index/distance. Though I think the requirements for insertion are mutually exclusive with that tbh.

Comment: What is the range for `n` and the values of the elements that you are supposed to store?

Comment: range upto 10^5 and values from -10^9 to 10^9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can augment any balanced-binary-search-tree data structure (e.g. a red-black tree) by including a "subtree size" data-member in each node (alongside the standard "left child", "right child", and "value" members). You can then calculate the number of elements less than a given element as you navigate downward from the root to that element.

It adds a fair bit of bookkeeping, and of course it means you need to use your own balanced-binary-search-tree implementation instead of one from the standard library; but it's quite doable, and it doesn't affect the asymptotic complexities of any of the operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use balanced BST with size of left subtree in each node to calculate distance